# how to convert an array string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

i am fetching an array from a PHP file and when I log the array on my console it displays as this: `[{"name":"zdfad","email":"XXX","phone":"XXX","id":"0","level":"1"}]`
as a string and not the as an array.

how can I fix this? this is the code:

```
fetch("./php/getuser.php", { method: "GET" })
.then((res) => res.text())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `res.text()` instead of `res.json()`?

Comment: use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Phil i totally forgot, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using `text()` which is asking fetch to read the response and resolve it as a string.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text

What you want is to replace `.text()` with `.json()`
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

This should work:

```
fetch("./php/getuser.php", { method: "GET" })
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use use the JavaScript [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to turn the string into a literal data type:

```js
JSON.parse("{ key: 'value' }");
```

Or, you can choose to use [Response.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) instead of text() so that you retrieve an object response.

Comment: Using `res.json()` should definitely be the preferred approach

Comment: @Phil exactly, that solved it